# Ajuda com básico em Javascript (timers)

Tags: php, javascript

a minha dúvida é a seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Joguinho</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div id="container">
        <?php
            $contador = 0;

            $random1 = (rand(1,10));
            $random2 = (rand(1,10));
            $resultado = $random1 * $random2;

            $contador++;
                echo("<div id='contador'>".$contador."/10"."</div>");
                echo("<div id='campo'>".$random1."x".$random2."</div>");
        ?>  
        <input id="digiteValor" type="text" />   
        <button id="enviar" onclick="chama()">Enviar</button>
        <div id="certoOuErrado"></div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function chama(){
        var valorDigitado = document.getElementById('digiteValor').value;   
        var resultado = "<?php echo $resultado; ?>";
        //var correto = "<div id='correto'></div>";
        //var incorreto = "<div id='incorreto'></div>";

            if(resultado == valorDigitado){
                document.getElementById('certoOuErrado').innerHTML = "CORRETO";
                //document.getElementById('certoOuErrado').innerHTML = correto;
                } else {
                document.getElementById('certoOuErrado').innerHTML = "INCORRETO";
                //document.getElementById('certoOuErrado').innerHTML = incorreto;
            }
        }

    </script> 
</html>
```

esse é o código que fiz até agora

a ideia é o rapaz digitar o valor, esperar um tempo pra verificar se a resposta está certa ou incorreta. eu tenho um contador que deverá contar 10 jogadas, é como se fosse um loop. Tem como dar refresh na tela e ficar atualizando esses dados até dar 10 jogadas? tem que ter um tempinho pra ele responder. por exemplo: tem 4seg pra responder, depois que o tempo acaba é verificado se o valor digitado está correto ou incorreto, dai vai pra próxima iteração.

Comment: Para executar um código dali a X milissegundos, use [`setTimeout(função, X);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) - ou para executar um código *a cada* X milissegundos, use [`setInterval(função, X);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). Nessa função você pode atualizar o valor de um elemento qualquer, usando `getElementById` (que eu vi no seu código que você sabe como usar). Experimente isso, e se ainda tiver dificuldades com a lógica, eu volto pra dar uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: P.S. Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e trazer o código relevante pra cá, em vez de colocar só um link pro pastebin (o código completo você deixa lá mesmo, só traz os trechos relevantes pra pergunta).

Answer (score 1):

Será mesmo que vale a pena utilizar php e ter que atualizar a pagina para gerar outros números aleatórios?

Você pode simplesmente utilizar Math.random() do javascript para tal, esta função gera um numero aleatório entre 0 e 1.

```js
var contador=0;
var acertos=0;
var erros=0;
function comecar(){
  if(contador==10){
  document.getElementById("operacao").innerHTML="acertos: "+acertos+" erros:"+erros;
    return false;
    }
  document.getElementById("resposta").value="";
  document.getElementById("resposta").disabled="";
  contador++;
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=contador+"/10";
  var numero1=Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
  var numero2=Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
  var resultado=numero1*numero2;
  document.getElementById("operacao").innerHTML=numero1+"x"+numero2;
  document.getElementById("enviar").onclick=function(e){
    var resposta=document.getElementById("resposta");
    resposta.disabled="true";
    if(resposta.value==resultado){
      resposta.value="correto";
      acertos++;
      }else if(resposta.value!=resultado){
        resposta.value="incorreto";
        erros++;
        }
    setTimeout(comecar,1000);
    }
  }
comecar();
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
<div id="operacao"></div>
<input id="resposta"/>
<input id="enviar" value="enviar" type="button">
```